# How to represent strings as floats?

Tags: c++

In a situation where we want to use floats instead of human-readable name strings for fast comparisons, are there usual methods for doing the conversion? The outcome of the comparison is a code-driven event, so there's no need to convert back again- it just has to be a very efficient process that creates a unique identifier.

Thanks!

Comment: The question does not make any sense at all

Comment: why floats? You could make a an integer hashcode, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114085/fast-string-hashing-algorithm-with-low-collision-rates-with-32-bit-integer

Comment: You could use any hashing function to get an integer, then convert the integer to a double. But there's no guarantee that the hash will be unique.

Comment: Look up "string hash code". The values wouldn't be unique, but the search would be a lot faster.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Integers to floats is not precise either.

Comment: Note that there's some floating point numbers such as NAN that aren't comparable, so you're better off using an integer if that's really the way you go.

Comment: @MarkRansom equality comparisons on floats are often problematic

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, just got done pointing that out, thanks. Although it's not a problem with floats generated by conversion from int.

Comment: @MarkRansom but then theres no point using a float, isn't it :) I think the question needs to be clarified

Comment: @EdHeal it is if the integer is small enough. A double can hold a 53 bit unsigned integer without loss.

Comment: Ok, not sure why that doesnt make sense. That was useful thumbmunkeys, thanks. Just found this as a result of your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094790/how-to-get-hash-code-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: @MarkRansom - Depends on the platform. Some platforms the ints are 64 bits

Comment: @RobbieCooper ok, I voted to close your question then

Comment: @EdHeal just because you don't understand the question, doesn't automatically mean it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @popovitsj - It does not make any sense in as much as it does not have any logic to it

Comment: Ok, this is all interesting stuff. So what do people do to create unique numbers? The strings are all generated before runtime, so is there another technique which addresses the same issue (speed) and guarantees unique results?

Comment: You're looking for a perfect hash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: @RobbieCooper _"So what do people do to create unique numbers?"_ They usually use [hashes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) (or [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)'s) :P ...

Comment: Thanks all, that has completely answered my question!